# Log and exponential uncertainty propogation

Tags: standard-error, error, poisson-regression, uncertainty, error-propagation

I am processing data on a radioactive decay experiment, and need to find the errors on some quantities that I can get from some fit parameters.

I would like to obtain:

- $\sigma A$ from $A = e^{a}$, where I have $a \pm \sigma a$
- $\sigma t_{\frac{1}{2}}$ from $t_{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{ln(2)}{k}$ where I have $k \pm \sigma k$

I've looked up many of the different sources  available explaining what looks like a fairly simple error propogation but just gotten myself very confused.

In the case of $\sigma A$, I think it's just $\sigma A = e^{\sigma a}$
In the case of $\sigma t_{\frac{1}{2}}$, I think it is $\sigma t_{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{\sigma k}{k} \times t$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with $A=e^a$ so $\delta_A = e^a \delta_a$

If $k=1/t$, you can find the answer in Sec 2 here: https://www.statisticshowto.com/error-propogation/

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Is my answer for the second part correct?

Comment: You question is quite unclear; for instance, what is $k$?

Comment: k is the decay constant.  I have $k \pm \sigma k$, and would like to calculate $\sigma t$. t is related to k by:  $t_{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{ln(2)}{k}$

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect